# phpファイルでデータをデータベースに追加すると?マークが付いてしまいます。

Tags: php, mysql

このようにデータベースにデータを追加すると、テーブルをmysqlで表示したときに？マークが付いてしまいます。

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbladdress
            (name, prefid, address, tel)
          VALUES
            (\"セレナ　ゴメス\", 21, \"東京都\", \"04-XXXX-9999\")";
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このように、「セレナ　ゴメス」の前、「東京都」の前に？が付いてしまいます。どうすれば
?が付かないようにできますか？

Comment: id33以外（特に、まともに見えるid20や完全に文字化けしてるid32）はどのように挿入したのでしょうか。id33と同じ方法ですか？

Answer (score 1):

MySQLでは、文字コードの設定を持っています。
?が表示されるのは、データベースの文字コードと参照しようとしているクライアントの文字コードが一致していない場合になります。

設定した意図がないようでしたら、おそらくデフォルトの文字コードが設定されているはずです。

その設定を確認するには、

```
show variables like "character-set-server";
```

とすると

utf8やsjisなどの値が出てくるはずです。

どの文字コードを利用したいかは、利用用途によるのでここでは一概に言えませんが、文字コードを意図したコードに設定することが重要かと思います。

設定するには、
my.confに

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=文字コード
```

などを設定しMySQLを再起動すると反映されるのではないかと思います。
文字コード周りはおざなりにすますと後々面倒が発生しやすいので、少し調査してみて設定をしてみることをおすすめします。

Answer (score 0):

DBやテーブルの文字セット、文字コードを確認してみてください。

Comment: 文字コードはUTF8になっています。文字セットとは何ですか？

Comment: 文字コードのことを文字セットと呼んだりするので、両方記載しました。

Comment: Mysqlの文字コードの定義は、DB単位、テーブル単位、カラム単位でそれぞれ指定できます。いずれか(たしかフィールドの文字コード)がデフォルトのlatinの状態で、UTF8の情報を保存すると上記のようになった気がしたのですが、再現ができませんでした。もしよかったらDBとテーブル、各フィールドの文字コードを教えてください。